# StackID Api issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, openid

I downloaded the StackID api from the following link http://code.google.com/p/stackid/source/checkout

I followed the instructions in the readme file but am still encountering an exception.

The site crashes on this line in the Current.cs file

```
    private static string SiteWideSalt { get { return KeyStore.GetKey(KeyStore.LatestKeyVersion).Salt; } }
```

The error I'm receiving is:

> The type initializer for 'OpenIdProvider.Helpers.KeyStore' threw an exception.
>
> {"Error converting value 1 to type 'OpenIdProvider.Helpers.KeyStore+Key'."} <--this is what's in the inner exception, which to me doesn't make sense since the property for value is byte and last I checked this should work with the number 1.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had some issues there.

After putting the content of the key-gen file in square brackets "[]" to make it a JSON array I had to restart IIS and it works fine now.

Comment: cool, thanks! If I'm working on this project again I'll try that.